# OData Select Syntax for Field SubString

Tags: sql, wcf, odata

Im pulling data across the line for a listing. Is there a way in OData syntax to only pull the first 100 characters of a field. e.g. EmployeeDescription field, I only want to show the first 100 characters of a Nvarchar(1000) database field.

Am trying to cut down as much as possible data going across the line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no support for such query. The projections feature ($select) only allows you to select which properties to get, but you will get the entire property value always.