# How can I use odata to return the first 10 characters of a string?

Tags: web-services, rest, service, substring, odata

Is it possible to have odata return the first 10 character of a string for one of the returned fields? For example if my string is 'abcdefghijklmno' I would want the odata service call to return 'abcdefghij'.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209830/odata-select-syntax-for-field-substring

Comment: There is no support for that in simple odata query. If you mean the server side, you can write specific logic to make it work.Or you need to write logic on your client side code.